# Запрос на изменение даты. Время должно оставаться без изменений

Tags: sql, sql-server

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Необходимо изменить дату заявок, но при этом оставить время как и было изначально указано.
Видел похожую тему, но тот вариант решение проблемы, вечно mssql выдает ошибку.

Так заменяю дату, но меняется и время на 00:00:00.000

```
update Application SET
registrationDate = '2022-06-11'
WHERE registrationdate  BETWEEN '2022-06-11 00:00:00.000' and '2022-06-11 23:59:59.000'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update Application SET
registrationDate = '2022-06-11' + ' ' + convert(varchar(20),registrationDate, 14)
WHERE registrationdate  BETWEEN '2022-06-11 00:00:00.000' and '2022-06-11 23:59:59.000'
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!